# Power Automate - Attachment does not have the actual name of the file

Tags: power-automate-desktop

In a flow that creates an email, I'm attaching an attachment to the mail.

[image]

The problem is that the file name is renamed.

**%Attachment%** has the value:
[https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Nord/Default/Company information gathering - Excel.xlsx](https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Nord/Default/Company%20information%20gathering%20-%20Excel.xlsx)

Becomes an attachment with the name:
**Company%20information%20gathering%20-%20Excel.xlsx**

I need the actual file name to be used, so without %20, without URL encode.

**Company information gathering -Excel.xlsx**

Comment: Can you add the part of your flow where you get the value for %Attachment%. What sharepoint actions are you using to get the value of %Attachment%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it..

*Get the file metadata* from sharepoint, the info is saved in `%GetFileMetadataResponse%`
[image: getmetadata]

Then get file content using *Get file content using path* using the ***Path*** value from metadata `%GetFileMetadataResponse.Path%` and store it in `%GetFileContentByPathResponse%`
[image: filecontent]

Then create a temp file by converting the binary data from the file content in `%GetFileContentByPathResponse%` using '**Convert binary to file**' action, getting the name from metadata `%GetFileMetadataResponse.Name%`.

[image: convertbinary]

Then assign variable `%attachment%` to temp file path `C:\temp\%GetFileMetadataResponse.Name%`

[image: setvariable]

and then use attachment as you usually would in send email.

[image: emailaatach]

The scenario is covered in the sharepoint [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/sharepoint)

Comment: Hi ConyC, this seems a good work around.
I will try this and set it as the answer if it works out fine. Thanks

Comment: Hi ConyC, this works fine, thanks.
To bad it does not work with the new outlook but I guess they will make it work?